# Is conferenceindex.org a reputable source?

Tags: conference, disreputable-publishers, scams

https://conferenceindex.org/

Is this a reputable website or a scam/predatory conference collection?

Comment: What does "authentic website" mean ? How can a website not be a website ?

Comment: This is the second question today that uses this terminology. I feel this is some "lost in translation" issue

Answer (score 1):

Probably the latter. For starters too many conferences are listed. Also you can just literally "Submit Your Event for FREE" as it says on the big green button up there, so anything would probably be able to be listed up there.

Answer (score 1):

I searched for a few good theoretical computer science conferences on that website, none of them were listed. On the other hand, the stuff they do list for computer science looks a lot like the conferences advertised via spam emails. While I can't rule out some decent conferences to be listed there, I do feel confident that being listed on this website is not at all an indication **for** the quality of the conference.